# calculate average in yii2

Tags: yii2, average

I am making a cost accounting application.

I want to find the average price over 3 months.

The summary produced in Kartik GridView shows initial share price not the total.

this is my controller

```html
<?php

namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use backend\models\Triwulan;
use backend\models\TriwulanSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
 * TriwulanController implements the CRUD actions for Triwulan model.
 */
class TriwulanController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Triwulan models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new TriwulanSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single Triwulan model.
     * @param string $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Triwulan model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Triwulan();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->rm_code]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing Triwulan model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param string $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->rm_code]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing Triwulan model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param string $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the Triwulan model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param string $id
     * @return Triwulan the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Triwulan::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
        }
    }
}
```

this is my view

```html
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;
use kartik\grid\GridView;


/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model backend\models\Triwulan */

$this->title = $model->rm_code;
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Triwulans', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="triwulan-view">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>


    <?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' => [
            'rm_code',
            'deskripsi_barang',
        ],
    ]) ?>

</div>
<?= GridView::widget([

       'dataProvider'=>new yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([

          'pagination'=>false,
           'query'=>$model->getPenerimaans(),

       ]),
       'columns'=>[
         ['class' => 'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],

          'rm_code',

              'bulan',
            //  'price',

              [
              'label' => 'Price',
              //'attribute' => 'idDhs.idMatakuliah.jam',
              'pageSummary' => true,
              //  'pageSummary' => 'Total',
              'value' => function ($model) {
                  if ($model)
                      return $model->price / 3; 
              }
              ],
        //      ['class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn'],

        //   'product',
          // 'qty'
       ],
       'showPageSummary' => true,

   ]) ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Update you question and show your related controller/action code .. plaese

Comment: i have done to update my code @scaisEdge, please help me

Answer (score 0):

Correcting some syntax errors from **scaisEdge's** answer

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new TriwulanSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);


    // calc the average
    $myAverage = 0;
    $myTot  =0;
    $myCnt = 0;
    foreach ($dataProvider->models as $key => $value) {
        $myTot += $value['price'];
        $cnt++; // This should be $myCnt
    }

    if ($cnt>0){  // inside if use $myCnt
      $myAverage = myTot/$myCont // here use $myTot/$myCnt

    }


    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,

       // render the avegare too
        'myAverage' => $myAverage,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: @scaisEdge : welcome..!! I just cleared syntax errors which you have not updated in your answer and from the comments of  "Putra Pratama", it looks like he is getting answer as zero. means error was not solved yet.

Comment: @Nitin    yes beacuse there was another error ..   look an the comment in answer ...